# No permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions

Output of `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwxrwx 16 btsync btsync 4096 Feb 25 15:41 documents
```

I can `cd` into the folder no problems. Now:

```
sudo chmod 776 documents
```

I can no longer `cd` into the folder:

```
bash: cd: documents: Permission denied
```

Even though:

```
$ groups $(whoami)
lp wheel network video audio storage btsync users
```

What is going on here? I belong to the group that owns the folder, so I should be able to `cd` into it.

Comment: did you try to re-login, if you added yourself to the group recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this user to the new group recently, note that new groups membership is applied after logging-in again.

Command

```
groups
```

gives you available groups in current shell, but

```
groups $(whoami)
```

returns the groups that you will get after re-login. You can also force the sync of the groups using `exec newgrp btsync`.

Comment: Note that you can see which groups you belong to and which groups you would belong to after logging-in again by specifiying the username argument or not to the group command. `groups` without the `$(whoami)` would have shown you that you were not a member of btsync as it list the groups of the current process, while `groups $(whoami)` reads them from /etc/group or whatever.

Comment: @user60039 Thanks. It was my thought, but I was not sure and too lazy to try that. :) Updated now.

Comment: Also instead of logging out, you can run `exec newgrp btsync` to join that group in that shell session ( the rest of your login session will still not be a member ).